# Godot tiles in tilemap sorting wrong

Tags: sorting, tiles, godot

can't find anything relative to this problem with tiles I'm facing

[image: 1]

This can be changed by flipping all tiles, but what is the proper way? What option shall I change? Tried many of them yet. Thanks for help

Comment: Often in this case, a `Y-sort`node is used to draw tiles in front based on their y-position, however, I'm not sure this will work for your specific scenario (unless it has some "invert" setting i'm not aware of). Another solution I've seen though, is to create 2 different tilemaps, and change the `z-order` of the one you want to be in front. Not ideal, I know, but it's something.

Comment: Found a workaround, if someone face the same issue, invert tiles horizontally and vertically and then rotate tilemap 180 degrees. Such a crutch, but it works!